# config.php working while app_dev.php and app.php doesn't

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony

I have a problem using Symfony2. I sent my website on my server, but as I said in the title, the website doesn't work.

In fact, when I try to access to the file `config.php`, it's working directly, but if I try to access to `app_dev.php` or `app.php` the webpage loads indefinitely and nothing comes.

That's happens only if set my IP address into `app_dev.php` for exemple. Otherwise I have:

> You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.

which is normal, but I think it's important to report that.

I really don't know where it can comes from, so any help is welcome.

EDIT:

Finally it seems to comes from APC which is bugging, so I switch it off.

Comment: Have you checked log files? (application in app/logs/ and server - probably /var/log/apache2/error.log if you are using apache)? And are you sure that app/logs and app/cache directories are writable? (chmod 777 preferably)

Comment: I checked them all, but there is nothing when i try to go on these pages. I only got new logs line if I go to config.php (which is working). Now concerning app/logs and app/cache, I have a windows server (so there's no chmod) but I think they are writable because when I go to properties/security and click on "everyone", all rights are granted.

Comment: are there actually any files & directories in app/cache and app/logs directories? sorry, I've never user windows server, don't know how to access error from this software

Comment: In app/cache there is many files and directories ; in app/logs there are 2 files, one for each environment (dev and prod).